# Compare types from Python typing

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have a function accepting another Python functions which are annotated with type hints (`__annotations__`). I would like to use those hints to do some type checking during runtime. The issue is that type classes from typing module does not seem very easy to work with (no isinstance, no issubclass). So, I wonder, is there a way to convert them to mypy type objects, and then use `mypy.subtypes.is_subtype` to compare types from type hints?

Comment: `inspect` module will  help.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is there is no easy way. The `typing` module is, by design, not going to provide much help for runtime checking. PEP 484 says

> This PEP aims to provide a standard syntax for type annotations,
>   opening up Python code to easier static analysis and refactoring,
>   potential runtime type checking, and (perhaps, in some contexts) code
>   generation utilizing type information.
>
> Of these goals, static analysis is the most important. This includes
>   support for off-line type checkers such as `mypy`, as well as providing
>   a standard notation that can be used by IDEs for code completion and
>   refactoring.
>
> **Non-goals**
>
> While the proposed `typing` module will contain some building
>   blocks for runtime type checking -- in particular the `get_type_hints()`
>   function -- third party packages would have to be developed to
>   implement specific runtime type checking functionality, for example
>   using decorators or metaclasses. Using type hints for performance
>   optimizations is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Yes, so my question is how to use `mypy` for runtime type checking. I understand that `typing` does not provide it, but how to plug `mypy` into the code to use its capabilities?